# Read whole html string Asyncsocket iOS

Tags: ios, client-side, asyncsocket, cocoaasyncsocket, cocoahttpserver

Hi I want to read from a server the whole html not only the request like
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK" 
I mean the html code too.
But I dont know how.
I am using the Asyncsocket library from "https://github.com/roustem/AsyncSocket"
have someone an idea how can i handle this?
i used the funktion

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag
```

but the data is to short and show me only the http request.

Thanks

Comment: Does that method get called more than once?  Are you sure the request you are sending actually produces any HTML output?

Comment: yes i am sure i send from an arduino webserver i tested on my normal browser

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are calling `readDataToData:timeout:tag:` using CRLF as the delimiter. That will return you one line of data. What you want is to read enough headers to tell how long the response data ought to be and then call `readDataToLength:timeout:tag:`, or else wait for the connection to be closed and call `unreadData` to get everything the server sent up to when it closed the connection.

The HTTP spec describes how to determine the length of the message: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4

Comment: Okay now I know what you mean but how can i find the length? i used " NSData *data = [AsyncSocket CRLFData];" and then readDataToLength:[data length] but it doenst work...

Comment: You need to call readDataToData with CRLFData until you get all the HTTP headers. Then you need to interpret the headers. One of them will tell you how long the data part (after the headers) is. Then you call readDataToLength with that length. See the ietf.org link I sent you.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer might be to use `NSURLConnection` to make the request and interpret the response for you.